# NUnit - specifying a method to be called after every test

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Does NUnit let me invoke a method after every test method?

e.g.

```
class SomeClass
{
   [SomeNUnitAttribute]
   public void CalledAfterEveryTest()
   {
   }
}
```

I'm aware of [SetUp] and [TearDown], but that only works for the tests in the current class. I want something like [TearDown], except it runs after *every* unit test, whether its in the current class or not. Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [TearDown] Attribute marks the cleanup method.

If you want it for multiple classes I believe you can add the teardown method to a base class and inherit from that in every test class that needs the teardown behaviour.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be an easier way. Well, thanks anyways, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Easier? how much easier can it get? write the method once and put : BaseTestClass after the name of your test class...